# put image in an absolute position in a linear layout

Tags: java, android, android-linearlayout, css-position, android-2.2-froyo

I have an android application I created with a menu with a set of buttons that are ordered one after the other.

I have a logo Icon that I want to pin to the bottom right corner of the page and to add it a margin. how can I do that ?

the page itself is in a LinearLayout. but I hope it is possible to add one element with an absoute position!  :)

I use android 2.2 sdk

thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use Nested Layouts..

```
<RelativeLayout>
  <LinearLayout>
    Place your elements and menu here.
  </LinearLayout>
  <ImageView
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```